# PyInstaller throws error module not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert .py to exe using pyinstaller using command

```
pyinstaller --onefile app.py
```

when i run the exe file it throws error

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
```

in this line , module not found

can some one help i am using python packages in my file

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from csv import reader
import json, requests, time, gspread, sys, re, calendar, traceback, string, unidecode, datetime
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
```

pyinsatller is unable to load the python packages without the imports exe is working fine

Removing python imports make it work 100%

I am using python 2.7

any help will be greatly aprreciated

Answer (score 2):

Pyinstaller might be having a problem with the alias you created. Try adding --hidden-import "bs4"

Ex:

```
    pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "bs4"  "./app.py"
```

Also, make sure pyinstaller is packaging using the correct interpreter. If you have other python interpreters they could be interfering. You can get the full path of the python executable by running

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

There is an open-source GUI for pyinstaller that helps:

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

To run just activate your virtualenv or conda environment and run in terminal:

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's worked for me :-

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "beautifulsoup4"  "app.py"
```