# unable to python exe when bs4 is imported

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyinstaller

```
import requests as requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from tabulate import tabulate
```

When ever use i try to use pyinstaller with this block of code
I get this error

```
18919 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\DILRREET\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.


IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

and when ever I remove bs4 import from my code It compiles successfully.

Comment: try with python 3.9

Comment: See if this link may help. Its another user having issues with bs4 and pyinstaller. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702163/pyinstaller-throws-error-module-not-found or this link: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/goh1fr/comment/frfqsje/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Thanks man. I was using python 3.10, degrading to 3.9 created it's exe successfully!

Comment: @BRUTE Please review the [tour], read [ask] and check the format of other posts to see what the best practices are for writing a question. SO offers tools to format code.

Comment: Sure! @eyllanesc